# Scraping data from Just Dial

Tags: python, csv, html-parser

```
# PIP requirements: requests, beautifulsoup4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv

jd_url = "http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Car-Hire-%3Cnear%3E-Shanthinagar"

# Split http/https prefix if any
# TODO: work on URLs which dont' have the CT part in URL
jd_url = jd_url.split('http://www.justdial.com/')[-1].split('https://www.justdial.com/')[-1]
city, search, cat_id = '', '', ''
split_vals = jd_url.split('/')
if len(split_vals) == 3:
    city, search, cat_id = jd_url.split('/')
    cat_id = cat_id.split('-')[-1]
elif len(split_vals) == 2:
    city, search = jd_url.split('/')
search = search.replace('-', '+')
```

I am using this script for scraping the fields mentioned in the script into csv file. I am facing an type error. I am very new to python pelase help.

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    #writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='\n')

    page = 1
    while True:
        print 'page', page
        resp = requests.get('http://www.justdial.com'+'/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city={0}&search={1}&where=&catid={2}&psearch=&prid=&page={3}'.format(city, search, cat_id, page))
        #markup = resp.json()
        markup = resp.json()['markup'].replace('\/', '/')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')


        for thing in soup.find_all('section'):
            csv_list = []
            if thing.get('class')==[u'jcar']:
                # Company name
                for a_tag in thing.find_all('a'):
                    if a_tag.get('onclick')=="_ct('clntnm', 'lspg');":
                        csv_list.append(a_tag.get('title'))

                # Address
                for span_tag in thing.find_all('span'):
                    if span_tag.get('class')==[u'mrehover', u'dn']:
                        csv_list.append(span_tag.get_text().strip())

                # Phone number
                # Phone_number
                for p_tag in thing.find_all('p'):
                    if p_tag.get('onclick')=="_ct('clntphn', 'lspg');":
                        csv_list.append(p_tag.get_text().strip())


                csv_list = ['"'+item+'"' for item in csv_list]
                writeline = ','.join(csv_list)+'\n'
                f.write(','.join(csv_list)+'\n')
        page+=1
```

I am eceiving a Type Error: list indices must be integers, not str
Please help me figure out.

Comment: I think the problem is when you make the request and then you try resp.json()["markup"]. I executed your code and resp.json() returns an empty list, so "markup" doesn't exist

Comment: Can you please edit the script for the same. It will be a great help @Roomm

Comment: Sorry but after trying a bit, I can't figure out why ajxSearch always returns an empty list. I think it's something related with request parameters or maybe the cookies the site sends on every request to ajxSearch.

Comment: I am trying at my end. Will post you soon again ASAP@Roomm

Comment: @SourabhChoudharyyou got any answer for this?

Comment: you can use selenium. Here is the tutorial link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkbF5JwuHqU&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=RoboPathshala

Answer (score 3):

This is the updated working just dail **scraper**.

you can check this out on github [here](https://github.com/harsh4870/Justdail-scrapper)

Answer (score 0):

JustDial data Extractor using selenium and python:

> https://github.com/alokm014/WhatsApp-Automation-Selenium